# Is it possible to deploy a distributed system on cloud?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, distributed, distributed-computing

I have a distributed tool that I want to run on cloud to benefit from cloud's elasticity and cost effectiveness. The tool is computationally expensive. The bigger the size of the problem that is being handled, the more resources needed.

The question is: does the cloud providers support deployment and execution of distributed applications? and is there anything special need to be tailored in the source of the tool for the cloud?

Comment: This is rather generic. To get a useful answer you'll need to give some detail about your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible. (But it may not as well depending on the application) 
Amazon EC2 offers auto scaling or you can set threshold levels or add resources to your cloud account. May be i can help more, if you tell more about application.

Comment: The tool generates a graph of states from a model and traverse the graph, the reason for using the cloud is because for big models, its possible the you run out of memory before your task is finished. I found that amazon EC2 offers high memory clusters which has 10GB Ethernet. This seems to be the best choice for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - depending on how your distributed application works.  The [Azure Auto-Scaling Block](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/) is the tool we use to scale (add additional Cloud Services) when memory or CPU reaches certain thresholds.